# how to remove filezilla from ubuntu

Tags: filezilla

I used the command to remove

```
sudo apt-get remove filezilla
```

But it is still in my machine. And I also used the following below command after using the first command

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: What you mean with "It is still in my machine" ?

Comment: Clarify 'but it is still in my machine'

Comment: @ElefantPhace i assume it was filezilla icon.

Answer (score 14):

To remove just file zilla :

```
sudo apt-get remove filezilla
```

Remove filezilla and it's dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove filezilla
```

Remove all your config data and file :

```
sudo apt-get purge filezilla
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove filezilla
```